# Computing multiple tasks with multiple workers simultaneously Dask

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I've 2 workers (`A` and `B`) with a `df` and  I'm trying to compute multiple descriptive stats with the following tasks:

```
Task 1: df.isnull().sum()
Task 2: df['column'].value_counts()
```

I want to assign `task1` to `A` and `task2` to `B` to parallelize the computation with dask.

From the documentation, it is not very clear how to achieve this. I have the following code:

```
future = client.compute(task1, task2, workers={task1: 'ipofA',task2: 'ipofB' })
future.result()
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

The second question is how can I assign `task1` to machine A and B, and `task2` to machine C?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
x = df.isnull().sum()
y = df['column'].value_counts()
x, y = dask.compute(x, y)
```

> The second question is how can I assign task1 to machine A and B, and task2 to machine C?

You shouldn't.  You should let Dask decide this as it sees best.